# Is it safe to delete Firebase CLI deployed images (of functions) in the Artifact Registry

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-artifact-registry

Is it safe to delete the images that are uploaded when a function is deployed using the Firebase CLI in the Artifact Registry? And does this safety measure apply to both Functions V1 and V2 as well? I'm wondering if the uploaded images serve any purpose beyond the deployment process, or if they can be safely removed once the deployment is complete. It would be helpful to know if there are any potential risks or dependencies associated with deleting these images.